# Windows 7 BSOD DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, safe mode working

Tags: bsod

I need help with my Windows 7 64-bit, Asus K52F laptop. After unintstalling ZoneAlarm and restarting my computer, the computer boots up with a BSOD: `driver_irql_not_less_or_equal`.

Afterwards as i tried booting the computer in saf-emode. I get the error message `A windows unexpected shutdown`:

> Problem Signature
>
> probrem event name : bluescreen
> os version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
> Locale ID: 4105
>
> Aditional information about the problem:
> BCCODE: d1
> BCP1: 0000000000000010
> BCP2: 0000000000000002
> BCP3: 0000000000000000
> BCP4: FFFFF880014E8566
> OS Version: 6_1_7601
> Service Pack: 1_0
> Product: 246_1
>
> Files that would help describe the problem:
> c:\windows\minidump\120612-13946-01.dmp
> c:\users(name)\appdata\local\temp\wer-25818-0.sysdata.xml

ALSO: i just tried recently, safe mode works, safe mode with command propt works, but safe mode with networking does not work. Is there a message from this?

Comment: upload the file c:\windows\minidump\120612-13946-01.dmp so that we can look at it with WinDbg

Answer (score 0):

Open these "files that would help" and look whats in there.

driver_irql_not_less_or_equal means, that a driver is missing or corrupted, what means, that you will have to reinstall it from the safe mode.

Only by looking into the files that could help you can see, what driver is missing.

Comment: what should i be looking for when i go into these files?

Comment: I also cannot open minidump so that would be useless. and cannot find the appdata file

Comment: @user178648 - There are programs that can do this.  Since your posting this, you must have some sort of access, you will need to get the file and open it.  We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure, if in Safe Mode you can see every file. If not, you'll first have to "unlock" them. In the explorer windows, go to Tools > Folder Options > View > Untick "Hide system operation files" and tick "Show hidden files and folders"

Comment: what should i be looking for when i look into the minidup folder?

Comment: @River2Apple copy the complete Minidump folder to the desktop, zip it and upload the zip to your dropbox or skydrive account and post the link here.

Comment: alright ill get to that tomorrow